# presets do not work when transforming code to es5

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, solid-js

I need to support the project on old browsers, so I need to transform the project into es5 format, the project is written using the SolidJS framework, and JSX files are compiled into js without problems, the problem itself is that the project does not work, that is, const remains in build.js , let, as well as arrow functions

What does my buildLoader look like

```
  const babelLoader = {
    test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    //include: [options.paths.src, options.paths.hls, options.paths.solidjs],
    // exclude: /node_modules/,
    exclude: [options.paths.corejs],
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        babelrc: false,
        configFile: false,
        sourceType: 'unambiguous',
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              useBuiltIns: 'usage',
              corejs: '3.27',
            },
          ],
          'solid',
          '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ],
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
          '@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions'
        ],
      },
    },
  };
```

Problem examples bundel.js

```
const _tmpl$ = /*#__PURE__*/(0,solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.template)(`<div></div>`, 2),
  _tmpl$2 = /*#__PURE__*/(0,solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.template)(`<li><div><div><div><p></p></div><p></p></div></div></li>`, 12);
function _defineAccessor(type, obj, key, fn) { var desc = { configurable: !0, enumerable: !0 }; return desc[type] = fn, Object.defineProperty(obj, key, desc); }
```

```
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "Modal": () => (/* reexport safe */ _Modal__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Modal)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _Modal__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./Modal */ "./src/components/modal/Modal.tsx");


/***/ }),
```

I would be glad for any hint, thanks for your attention :)

I've tried changing the target, installing additional plugins to replace arrow functions, and so on. but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not caused by Solid but by the bundler. As far as I know you need to specify target browsers:

> By default @babel/preset-env will use browserslist config sources unless either the targets or ignoreBrowserslistConfig options are set.

> When no targets are specified: Babel will assume you are targeting the oldest browsers possible. For example, @babel/preset-env will transform all ES2015-ES2020 code to be ES5 compatible.

https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-env#browserslist-integration

That being said,try directly targeting an older browser.

> Although we typically recommend not compiling node_modules, you may need to when using libraries that do not support IE 11 or any legacy targets.

> For this, you can either use a combination of test and not, or pass a function to your exclude option. You can also use negative lookahead regex as suggested here.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#some-files-in-my-node_modules-are-not-transpiled-for-ie-11